# what is the solution of Error in TCl script?

Tags: tcl, verilog, modelsim, intel-fpga

I recently downloaded Modelsim 10.1 from altera.com and i am getting this message of "Error in TCL script". I am not able to start a new verilog project.
Here is the error

```
Trace back: can't read "Project(SaveCompileReport)": no such element in array
    while executing
"if { $Project(SaveCompileReport) } {
                      Project::saveCompileReport
              }"
    (procedure "Project::unload" line 20)
    invoked from within
"Project::unload"
    (procedure "Project::checkCloseCurrentProject" line 24)
    invoked from within
"Project::checkCloseCurrentProject"
    (procedure "Project::createDialog" line 18)
    invoked from within
"Project::createDialog"
    (menu invoke)
   <2: ::tkerror {can't read "Project(SaveCompileReport)": no such element in array}
   <1: ::bgerror {can't read "Project(SaveCompileReport)": no such element in array}
```

Please if anyone can provide me a solution.

Comment: You should rather ask this question at [AlteraForum](http://www.alteraforum.com).

Comment: And once you've got an answer there, do come back here and write it up here so that other people can find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error some time back. This can be resolved by **deleting** your work folder/ whatever **deletes the project file of the project** it is trying to load in the ModelSim.

Simply uninstalling and installing again won't work .

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. add to that, immediately close ModelSim and then open it,then start the new project